# Are there any MongoDB java testing framework to 'mock' mongo interactions?

Tags: java, mongodb, testing

I'm looking for a MongoDB testing framework. Is there anything available for an in-memory implementation that mocks/intercepts calls to mongoDB for CRUD operations and other methods?

In my research, the best/closet thing I've found was a pet project called "Fongo" here
[Githbub Fongo Project](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo)

Are there any better, more established ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

No, and I wouldn't recommend it.  There is a general principle of mocking that applies here: don't mock what you don't own.  In this case, you don't own MongoDB or the MongoDB driver, and part of what you should be testing is that your application is using MongoDB and the driver correctly. If you want to use mocks for something, it would be more appropriate to mock at the DAO layer in your application.